# 1-week study plan to read chapters 1-5 of Boyd & Vandenberghe

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, self-learning, machine-learning, lagrange-multiplier

Assume I have enough mathematical background to understand chapters 1-5 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook). Which are the most essential sections that I should read within a week?

The reason I want to read the book is because I have trouble understanding the use of Lagrange multipliers in [support-vector machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine) (SVMs), discussed in Bishop's [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387310732). Someone suggested the first 5 chapters could help me.

Comment: Maybe try reading sections 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, 3.2, 4.1, 4.2, 5.1 - 5.5, and section 8.6 (which actually explains support vector machines). Backtrack and fill in gaps as needed.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?